# How to achieve "resumption semantics" for Python exceptions?

Tags: python, exception

I have a validator class with a method that performs multiple checks and may raise different exceptions:

```py
class Validator:
    def validate(something) -> None:
        if a:
            raise ErrorA()
        if b:
            raise ErrorB()
        if c:
            raise ErrorC()
```

There's a place in the outside (caller) code where I want to customize its behaviour and prevent `ErrorB` from being raised, without preventing `ErrorC`. Something like [resumption semantics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Termination_and_resumption_semantics) would be useful here. Hovewer, I haven't found a good way to achieve this.

To clarify: I have the control over `Validator` source code, but prefer to preserve its existing interface as much as possible.

Some possible solutions that I've considered:

1. The obvious

   ```py
   try:
       validator.validate(something)
   except ErrorB:
       ...
   ```

   is no good because it also suppresses `ErrorC` in cases where both `ErrorB` and `ErrorC` should be raised.
2. Copy-paste the method and remove the check:

   ```py
   # In the caller module

   class CustomValidator(Validator):
       def validate(something) -> None:
           if a:
               raise ErrorA()
           if c:
               raise ErrorC()
   ```

   Duplicating the logic for `a` and `c` is a bad idea
   and will lead to bugs if `Validator` changes.
3. Split the method into separate checks:

   ```py
   class Validator:
       def validate(something) -> None:
           self.validate_a(something)
           self.validate_b(something)
           self.validate_c(something)

       def validate_a(something) -> None:
           if a:
               raise ErrorA()

       def validate_b(something) -> None:
           if b:
               raise ErrorB()

       def validate_c(something) -> None:
           if c:
               raise ErrorC()

   # In the caller module

   class CustomValidator(Validator):
       def validate(something) -> None:
           super().validate_a(something)
           super().validate_c(something)
   ```

   This is just a slightly better copy-paste.
   If some `validate_d()` is added later, we have a bug in `CustomValidator`.
4. Add some suppression logic by hand:

   ```py
   class Validator:
       def validate(something, *, suppress: list[Type[Exception]] = []) -> None:
           if a:
               self._raise(ErrorA(), suppress)
           if b:
               self._raise(ErrorB(), suppress)
           if c:
               self._raise(ErrorC(), suppress)

       def _raise(self, e: Exception, suppress: list[Type[Exception]]) -> None:
           with contextlib.suppress(*suppress):
               raise e
   ```

   This is what I'm leaning towards at the moment.
   There's a new optional parameter and the `raise` syntax becomes kinda ugly,
   but this is an acceptable cost.
5. Add flags that disable some checks:

   ```py
   class Validator:
       def validate(something, *, check_a: bool = True,
                    check_b: bool = True, check_c: bool = True) -> None:
           if check_a and a:
               raise ErrorA()
           if check_b and b:
               raise ErrorB()       
           if check_c and c:
               raise ErrorC()
   ```

   This is good, because it allows to granually control different checks even
   if they raise the same exception.

   However, it feels verbose and will require additional maintainance
   as `Validator` changes. I actually have more than three checks there.
6. Yield exceptions by value:

   ```py
   class Validator:
       def validate(something) -> Iterator[Exception]:
           if a:
               yield ErrorA()
           if b:
               yield ErrorB()
           if c:
               yield ErrorC()
   ```

   This is bad, because it's a breaking change for existing callers
   and it makes propagating the exception (the typical use) way more verbose:

   ```py
   # Instead of
   # validator.validate(something)

   e = next(validator.validate(something), None)
   if e is not None:
       raise e
   ```

   Even if we keep everything backwards-compatible

   ```py
   class Validator:
       def validate(something) -> None:
           e = next(self.iter_errors(something), None)
           if e is not None:
               raise e

       def iter_errors(something) -> Iterator[Exception]:
           if a:
               yield ErrorA()
           if b:
               yield ErrorB()
           if c:
               yield ErrorC()
   ```

   The new suppressing caller still needs to write all this code:

   ```py
   exceptions = validator.iter_errors(something)
   e = next(exceptions, None)
   if isinstance(e, ErrorB):
       # Skip ErrorB, don't raise it.
       e = next(exceptions, None)
   if e is not None:
       raise e
   ```

   Compared to the previous two options:

   ```py
   validator.validate(something, suppress=[ErrorB])
   ```

   ```py
   validator.validate(something, check_b=False)
   ```

Comment: Option 1 does not suppress `C` from being raised; the fact that `B` gets raised at all prevents `C` from being raised. Since Python simply does *not* support resumption semantics, you will have to modify `Validator` *somehow*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bare exceptions you are looking at the wrong tool for the job. In Python, to `raise` an exception means that execution hits an *exceptional case* in which resuming *is not possible*. Terminating the broken execution is an express purpose of exceptions.

> #### [Execution Model: 4.3. Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/executionmodel.html#exceptions)
>
> Python uses the “termination” model of error handling: an exception handler can find out what happened and continue execution at an outer level, but it cannot repair the cause of the error and retry the failing operation (except by re-entering the offending piece of code from the top).

To get resumption semantics for exception handling, you can look at the generic tools for either *resumption* or for *handling*.

---

#### Resumption: Coroutines

Python's resumption model are *coroutines*: `yield` coroutine-generators or `async` coroutines both allow to pause and explicitly resume execution.

```
def validate(something) -> Iterator[Exception]:
    if a:
        yield ErrorA()
    if b:
        yield ErrorB()
    if c:
        yield ErrorC()
```

It is important to distinguish between `send`-style "proper" coroutines and iterator-style "generator" coroutines. As long as no value must be sent *into* the coroutine, it is functionally equivalent to an iterator. Python has good inbuilt support for working with iterators:

```py
for e in validator.iter_errors(something):
    if isinstance(e, ErrorB):
        continue  # continue even if ErrorB happens
    raise e
```

Similarly, one could `filter` the iterator or use comprehensions. Iterators easily compose and gracefully terminate, making them suitable for iterating exception cases.

---

##### Effect Handling

Exception handling is just the common use case for the more generic *effect handling*. While Python has no builtin effect handling support, simple handlers that address only the origin or sink of an effect can be modelled just as functions:

```py
def default_handler(failure: BaseException):
    raise failure

def validate(something, failure_handler = default_handler) -> None:
    if a:
        failure_handler(ErrorA())
    if b:
        failure_handler(ErrorB())
    if c:
        failure_handler(ErrorC())
```

This allows the caller to change the effect handling by supplying a different handler.

```py
def ignore_b_handler(failure: BaseException):
    if not isinstance(failure, ErrorB):
        raise failure

validate(..., ignore_b_handler)
```

This might seem familiar to dependency inversion and is in fact related to it.

There are various stages of buying into effect handling, and it is possible to reproduce much if not all features via classes. Aside from technical functionality, one can implement ambient effect handlers (similar to how `try` "connects" to `raise` automatically) via [thread local](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.local) or [context-local](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) variables.

Comment: A lot of good points here. I need to experiment first, but I'll probably use the `iter_errors()` approach. Libraries like [jsonschema](https://github.com/python-jsonschema/jsonschema) seem to use it as well

Answer (score 1):

Another spin on option 4:

```py
class Validator:
    def validate(something, *, suppress: tuple[Type[Exception], ...] = ()) -> None:
        def _raise(e: Exception) -> None:
            with contextlib.suppress(*suppress):
                raise e

        if a:
            _raise(ErrorA())
        if b:
            _raise(ErrorB())
        if c:
            _raise(ErrorC())
```

The `raise` part looks cleaner now. But I'm not sure if I'll use this, because I actually have multiple `validate()`-like methods, and each would have to define the same closure.

Comment: You can make a decorator that does a bit of argument rewriting! I'll post another answer. This is a fun question!

Comment: Don't use mutable default args btw, it's a newb trap with 3k upvotes and the most popular Python question about surprising side effects ;P

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper I'm aware the of mutable args gotcha. Here, I'm just confident enough that `suppress` is going to be used as an immutable list. But yeah, I probably should've used a `Tuple`.

Comment: I always avoid it on StackOverflow anyway, given that 25% of answers are copy pasted verbatim and then lead a life on their own.

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires some rewriting of the original code to allow for your surppression semantics, but it feels rather clean. You wrap each `raise` in a context manager that checks a suppression object:

```
class SuppressionManager:
  def __init__(self, suppress=None):
    self.suppress = suppress or []

  def __enter__(self):
    pass

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    if exc_type in self.suppress:
      pass
    else:
      raise exc_val from None
```

Then in your function:

```
class Validator:
    def validate(something, suppress=None) -> None:
        mgr = SuppressionManager(suppress)
        if a:
            with mgr:
                raise ErrorA()
        if b:
            with mgr:
                raise ErrorB()
        if c:
            with mgr:
                raise ErrorC()
```

Now noone needs to change anything :) If you don't control the code inside `validate`, I propose source code inspection, and rewrite the AST to wrap each raise statement, recompile it, and monkey patch it in.

Comment: You even control where the code resumes somewhat, by what you put inside of the with block. With a small extension to the manager, you can even keep track of what was suppressed, and apply conditional "finalizing" logic, or except logic.

Comment: This is basically a variation of the option 4. I'd probably just use `with contextlib.suppress(*suppress)` instead of the custom manager. I've just exctracted this into a separate function because I didn't like the extra indent. But this is just personal taste.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that I control the `validate()` code. But your AST workaround sounds like a fun idea for a PyPI package

Comment: I've posted another variation as an answer

Comment: Oh, didn't spot option 4, my bad, pretty big answer, scrolled right past it :D

Answer (score 0):

You can either make a mixin class that uses `__init_subclass__` to apply this to the `validate` method, or, more conventional, use a decorator:

```
class Validator:
    @suppressed_raise
    def validate(something, *, suppressed_raise) -> None:
        if a:
            suppressed_raise(ErrorA())
        if b:
            suppressed_raise(ErrorB())
        if c:
            suppressed_raise(ErrorC())
```

```
import functools
import inspect
import contextlib

def suppressed_raise(f):
 sig = inspect.signature(f)
 @functools.wraps(f)
 def decorated(*args, *, suppress: list[Type[Exception]] = None, **kwargs):
  def raise_(e: Exception) -> None:
   with contextlib.suppress(*(suppress or [])):
    raise e

  bound = sig.bind_partial(*args, **kwargs)
  bound.arguments["suppressed_raise"] = raise_
  return f(**bound.args, **bound.kwargs)

 return decorated
```

This will rewrite the `suppress` list, into a ready-to-use `suppressed_raise` function, so the caller gives a list of exceptions to suppress, and the method can use `suppressed_raise` to raise their exceptions.

Comment: I'm getting "Suggested edit queue is full", so posting in the comments. Typos in your code and how to fix them: `*args, *,` -> `*args,`, `**bound.args` -> `*bound.args`

Comment: Smart solution, but to me it feels like an overkill and too complex to use in the real code. First, it implicitly depends on the parameter being named exactly `suppressed_raise`. Second, with type hints it gets confusing for the reader. The original function accepts a `Callable[[Exception], None]`, but when it's decorated, it actually needs to be called with a `list[Type[Exception]] | None`. Usually, decorators don't change the existing interface

Comment: Something like this needs to be explicitly documented anyway, and you can rewrite the signature as you like so that it fits: `validate(something, suppressed_raise=None, suppress=None)` and add both type hints. There's no other way to create parameter decorators in Python than either through coupling to the position, or name of the parameter.

Comment: A decorator or mixin class would be the only way to automate the closure of option 4